# Some questions when using HogDescriptor in OpenCv3.0 under Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I want to use HOGDescriptor of OpenCv3.0 under VS2012.And my codes is flows:

```
    cv::Mat  img=cv::imread("D:\\pictures\\1.bmp";

    if(img.data==NULL)

    {

         cout<<"load pictures error"<<endl;

    }

    if(img.cols!=hog.winSize.width||img.rows!=hog.winSize.height)

    {

        count<<"the size of pictures is wrong"<<endl;

    }

    cv::HOGDescriptor;

     hog(cv::Size(64,64),cv::Size(16,16),cv::Size(8,8),cv::Size(8,8),9);

    vector<float> featureVec;

    hog.compute(img,featureVec);

//fails，"Access error occurred while writing position 0 x00477218”
```

I examine the codes many times, and don't why.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect types in your code.

As per documentation ([Openc 3.0 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a650b09f36f1e385dc4cc4354f1779256)) your `featureVec` has to be vector of Points. Not vector of floats.

Relevant part of docs:

```
virtual void cv::HOGDescriptor::detect  (   const Mat &     img,
        std::vector< Point > &      foundLocations,
        double      hitThreshold = 0,
        Size    winStride = Size(),
        Size    padding = Size(),
        const std::vector< Point > &    searchLocations = std::vector< Point >() 
    )       const
```

So in your code try following:

```
vector<cv::Point> featureVec;
hog.compute(img,featureVec);
```

It interesting that the code event compile, if the types don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `HoG.compute(img,featureVec)` with default parameters, i.e. don't give window sizes when declaring your HOG variable. It sounds like a parameter is wrong ...

Detect is a different method, so the call is correct